How to load data into firebase emulator using docker-compose?
I'm using this repo to create an emulator for my project to test it. I don't overwrite firebase.json file, I just cloned the repository into my workfolder. I have some data in my cloud firebase that I want to load into the emulator. I've managed to export all of it into a JSON file as was described in this video using cmd.
In the Dockerfile there is a command that imports/exports data to the database:
CMD ["--non-interactive", "emulators:start", "--import", "./data", "--export-on-exit", "./data"]

I have created folder data and put my file inside.
When I run docker-compose up I get this:

I have also tried to import my JSON file manually in the emulator while it was running, but it just shows this:

Could you please explain how to do this? Thanks in advance.
